# How to get file's owner name in Linux using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, file-ownership

How can I get get the owner name and group name of a file on a Linux filesystem using C++? The `stat()` call only gives me owner ID and group ID but not the actual name.

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 john devl  3052 Sep  6 18:10 blah.txt
```

How can I get 'john' and 'devl' programmatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`getpwuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) and [`getgrgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgrgid.html).

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat info;
stat(filename, &info);  // Error check omitted
struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(info.st_uid);
struct group  *gr = getgrgid(info.st_gid);

// If pw != 0, pw->pw_name contains the user name
// If gr != 0, gr->gr_name contains the group name
```

Comment: For completeness note that *"getpwnam() and getpwuid() search the password database for the given login name or user uid, respectively, **always returning the first one encountered**"* (emphasis added) because one UID can be associated with more than one username (thought this is generally frowned upon).

Comment: Fair comment.  One of the banes of my life is that the local group file has multiple entries for GID 1234 with different names.  It tends to mean `getgrent()` to find whether user `jdoe` is actually a member of group 1234.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to get the uid of a file and then [`getpwuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) to get the username as a string.